# Need to create seperate mode for same template by using the attribute value

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need the two types of output by using the single XSL depends upon the Input root attribute value:

My Input first type xml (rare case) would be:

```
<topic outputclass="inter">
       <title class="- topic/title "/>
       <body class="- topic/body ">
              <bodydiv class="- topic/bodydiv ">
                     <xref class="- topic/xref " format="html" href="inter.html" scope="external"/>
              </bodydiv>
       </body>
</topic>
```

Inner.html which is mentioned in href attribute considering:

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <p>this is a new</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My second type xml (regular) would be:

```
<topic outputclass="outer">
       <title class="- topic/title "/>
       <body class="- topic/body ">
              <bodydiv class="- topic/bodydiv ">
                    <xref class="- topic/xref " href="123.png" />
              </bodydiv>
       </body>
</topic>
```

XSL I have tried is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:r="http://www.Corecms.com/Core/ns/metadata" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
    xmlns:df="http://dita2indesign.org/dita/functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd r exsl xhtml ditaarch df" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="doctypePublic" select="'public'" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:param name="doctypeSystem" select="'system'" as="xs:string?"/>

    <xsl:param name="Core.sessionkey" as="xs:string" select="'unset'"/>
    <xsl:param name="Core.serverurl" as="xs:string" select="'urn:unset:/dev/null'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="debug" select="'yes'" as="xs:string?"/>

    <xsl:function name="df:class" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="elem" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:param name="classSpec" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:variable name="normalizedClassSpec" as="xs:string" select="normalize-space($classSpec)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result"
            select="matches($elem/@class, concat(' ', $normalizedClassSpec, ' | ', $normalizedClassSpec, '$'))"
            as="xs:boolean"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="html">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$html"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')]">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(ancestor::*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')])">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-comments"/>
                    </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/title')][parent::*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')]]">
        <xsl:variable name="headingLevel" select="count(ancestor::*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')])"
            as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:element name="h{$headingLevel}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/body')]">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/bodydiv')]">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/p')]">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/xref')]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". != ''">
                <a>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <a>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                </a>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output for the first type of xml is:

```
<div>
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <p>this is a new</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</div>
```

I have achieved the above output by changed the below code in topic/xref template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/xref')]">
      <div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

But for the second type xml (outputclass="outer") is not working. I don't want to disturb the existing XSL file for second type of xml files. Because that only the huge.So needs to create new mode with same template or using If statement for xref template for html fetching types.

I'm new to the XSL. Your help will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what "is not working"? What output (or error) are you getting, and what output do you actually expect? Thank you!

Comment: <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/xref')]"> is not working for the second type of xml, If I changed the template by using document(@href).

Comment: Yes, because `document` will only work for reading files with XML (or XHTML) in, but in your second XML it looks like you are referencing an image. Do you want to show an `<img src="123.png" />` in this case?

Comment: Thanks @Tim. No. I don't want that Image. needs to be blank on that line. But have to write the template by using the topic outputclass of xml only in the topic/xref template.

Comment: What happens if you change `<xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)"/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="if (doc-available(@href)) then doc(@href) else ()"/>`, do you then get the result you want?

Comment: @MartinHonnen. Thanks. Then also its getting working. But I'm getting output with <h1> and lot of <div> items in the output. I need only the Expected output for the first type of xml (I have mentioned in the question). Please see.